# List manipulation in python

Tags: python, list

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#TODO: Make it more dynamic
for a in range(0, len(list_a)):
    for b in range(0, len(list_b)):
            foobar[a][b].append(sum(float(\
                    foo[0][a][b][0]+\
                        foo[1][a][b][0]+\
                        foo[2][a][b][0]+\
                        foo[3][a][b][0])))
```

I am trying to do some `summation`  and the above code snippet shows that. 
I was wondering how to extend it for work for any `number elements in foo.` 
For example: If I have `foo` of length `10 or 100`. 
It is a list manipulation but i don't know if there is a `function` for it in `python 2.7`

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about list generator:

```
for a in range(0, len(list_a)):
    for b in range(0, len(list_b)):
        sum_foo = float(sum([x[a][b][0] for x in foo]))
        foobar[a][b].append(sum_foo)
```